# The expectation is zero

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expectation, martingales

I do not understand how they have $\mathbb{E}(A_{j-1}(M_j - M_{j-1})) = 0$ in the example. From the martingale property, we just conclude $\mathbb{E}(M_j - M_{j-1}) = 0$, don't we?

[image]

Thank you very much for any explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The martingale property says that the *conditional 
expectation* is zero, i.e., $\mathbb{E}(M_j-M_{j-1}\mid {\cal F}_{j-1})=0$.
This is much stronger than just $\mathbb{E}(M_j-M_{j-1})=0$.

Since the process $(A_n)$ is adapted, we know that 
 $A_{j-1}$ is ${\cal F}_{j-1}$-measurable and so we can 
pull it out of the conditional expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}(A_{j-1}(M_j-M_{j-1}) \mid {\cal F}_{j-1})=A_{j-1}\,\mathbb{E}(M_j-M_{j-1}\mid {\cal F}_{j-1})=A_{j-1}\cdot0=0.\tag1$$
Taking expected values in (1) gives $\mathbb{E}(A_{j-1}(M_j-M_{j-1}))=0.$